# Return pymongo bulk object?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, bulkinsert

I have an "outer" Python function that iterates over all documents of a MongoDB collection and creates/updates them accordingly using the bulk API. There is a counter and a batch size, so when the counter is equal to the batch size, there is a `bulk.execute()` command, and a reinitialization of both the counter and the bulk object.

This outer function is rather "lean" - it consists of an iterator over all unique IDs of these documents and of the execution/reset of bulk when the counter hits the predetermined batch size. For each unique ID, the "inner" function that deals with each individual document is called, and this is where most of the work is done.

Now, within the inner function I also need to update some documents of another MongoDB collection, so I am thinking of doing it using a separate bulk operation.

My question is:
Should I define/execute/reset the second bulk object within my inner function? Or should I define it within the outer function, pass it as an argument into the inner function, and execute it along with the other bulk object outside, when the counter meets the batch size requirement? And in this case, is the second bulk object updated by reference, or should I also have it as a second return/output of the inner function?

EDIT: There is the structure of my code:

```
def update_collection(db, batch_size=10000):
    bulk_1 = db.collection_1.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
    [...]
    for unique_id in unique_ids:
        updated_doc = update_doc(db, unique_id)
        if updated_doc != None:
            count += 1
            bulk_1.find({'unique_id': unique_id}).upsert().update({'$set':updated_doc})


def update_doc(db, unique_id):
    doc = db.collection_1.find_one({'unique_id': unique_id})
    bulk_2.find({'other_unique_id': doc['other_unique_id']}).update(...)
```

The question is:
Should I define bulk_2 within the update_collection function (where the execute/reset takes place? Does the bulk_2 update gets updated by reference, even though it lives in the inner, update_doc function?

Comment: If you call `.execute()` then you cannot call `.execute()` again unless you re-initialize. If you don't you get an error. If your question is that you are unsure of where to place, then show at least some minimal code representing the loop structure.

Comment: So `bulk_find2` is operating on a different collection to `collection_1` right? I'm not really seeing the whole process as the detail/purpose is no doubt evident in the post not posted here. Couple of points of concern though. You are calling `.find_one()` repeatedly inside that function, which basically means once per each loop iteration of `unique_ids`. It seems to me that your "loop" should probably be iterating a "cursor" which is retrieving those documents right at the start. Also concerned that you think this function needs to return a value. I would put some serious thought into that.

Comment: As for the general principle, well the idea should generally be that when "each" bulk operation has a range that generally speaking does not exceed 1000 items ( at which point the API is going to split the batch anyway ) then you send to the server with `.execute()`. At which point each "queue" reaches that operations count is unclear in your question as currently presented. As the code presently looks, the "accumulation" for the "two bulk statements" is `1:1`, therefore you "should" be able to track one counter and execute at the same time. But that is based on code currently shown.